# How to sum certain columns ending a certain word of a dataframe in python pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get 'summing' of columns ending 'Load' and 'Gen' to two new columns.
My dataframe is:

```
Date      A_Gen  A_Load  B_Gen  B_Load 
1-1-2010    30      20      40   30  
1-2-2010    45      25      35   25
```

The result wanted is:

```
Date      A_Gen  A_Load  B_Gen  B_Load  S_Gen  S_Load 
1-1-2010    30      20      40   30     70      50
1-2-2010    45      25      35   25     80      50
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `filter(like='..')` to get the relevant columns, sum along `axis=1`, and return your 2 new columns:

```
df['S_Gen'] , df['B_Load'] =  df.filter(like='Load').sum(1) , df.filter(like='Gen').sum(1)
```

**Output**:

```
df
Out[146]: 
        Date  A_Gen  A_Load  B_Gen  B_Load  S_Gen
0 2010-01-01     30      20     40      70     50
1 2010-02-01     45      25     35      80     50
```